# WMS is for raster... What is for vector layers?

Tags: vector, web-mapping, vector-tiles, web-service

From my understanding, standards such as WMS, TMS etc are mainly used to fetch raster layers from a map server.

What are the popular options for serving vector layers?
Can it be tiled or not tiled as well?

Comment: I'd like to solve: Questions with lack of research, 300: The answer is: WFS.

Comment: Don't confuse `fetch` and `serve`. It is very common to fetch vector data and to serve it as an image via WMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WFS. Web Feature Service would be the vector equivalent of WMS.

For tiles vectors there is vector tiles, which can be served through TMS. For example with GeoServer: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html

Comment: Vector tiles can be served through a WMS too, for example MapServer can do this

Comment: WFS is really the equivalent of WCS, both provide downloads of data.  WMS allows for viewing and querying of data but doesn't provide access; source data can be vector or raster